# "How old were you when you *went to the pen*?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from the movie *Stagecoach* (1939):

> – Say, kid. How old were you when you **went to the pen**?
>
> – I was about 17.

What does it mean? I guess it might mean 'to go to prison' (penitentiary) or 'to have sex' (he went to the pen full of hens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's prison as you guessed. Because one can *go* to the prison and not *sex* (at least the way it appears here).

You mentioned that he *went to the pen full of hens* - is this your guess or an input? In this case, the word *pen* may *still* mean [fenced enclosure.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pen) which was full of hens? But I think it's *prison* here.

> [pen (n; #4)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pen) - A penitentiary; a prison.

However, it shows that the word is *informal.*